# Wordpress Get First and Last Name

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the first name of a user in Wordpress by using the following code:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
var_dump($current_user);
```

... and my output is at the end of the post.

According [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo#Default_Usage), I should be able to fetch the user's first and last name. However, mimicking their example would be fruitless, since neither `user_firstname` nor `user_lastname` show up in this variable dump

Any ideas on why not? I am using Wordpress 3.5.1 and my WP account does have the first and last name set.

Thank you for your time.

**Output:**

```
object(WP_User)[113]
  public 'data' => 
    object(stdClass)[115]
      public 'ID' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'user_login' => string 'stuff' (length=16)
      public 'user_pass' => string 'stuff' (length=34)
      public 'user_nicename' => string 'stuff' (length=15)
      public 'user_email' => string 'stuff' (length=16)
      public 'user_url' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'user_registered' => string '2013-03-24 16:54:43' (length=19)
      public 'user_activation_key' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'user_status' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'display_name' => string 'stuff' (length=12)
  public 'ID' => int 1
  public 'caps' => 
    array (size=1)
      'administrator' => boolean true
  public 'cap_key' => string 'wp_capabilities' (length=15)
  public 'roles' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'administrator' (length=13)
  public 'allcaps' => 
    array (size=63)
      'switch_themes' => boolean true
      'edit_themes' => boolean true
      'activate_plugins' => boolean true
      'edit_plugins' => boolean true
      'edit_users' => boolean true
      'edit_files' => boolean true
      'manage_options' => boolean true
      'moderate_comments' => boolean true
      'manage_categories' => boolean true
      'manage_links' => boolean true
      'upload_files' => boolean true
      'import' => boolean true
      'unfiltered_html' => boolean true
      'edit_posts' => boolean true
      'edit_others_posts' => boolean true
      'edit_published_posts' => boolean true
      'publish_posts' => boolean true
      'edit_pages' => boolean true
      'read' => boolean true
      'level_10' => boolean true
      'level_9' => boolean true
      'level_8' => boolean true
      'level_7' => boolean true
      'level_6' => boolean true
      'level_5' => boolean true
      'level_4' => boolean true
      'level_3' => boolean true
      'level_2' => boolean true
      'level_1' => boolean true
      'level_0' => boolean true
      'edit_others_pages' => boolean true
      'edit_published_pages' => boolean true
      'publish_pages' => boolean true
      'delete_pages' => boolean true
      'delete_others_pages' => boolean true
      'delete_published_pages' => boolean true
      'delete_posts' => boolean true
      'delete_others_posts' => boolean true
      'delete_published_posts' => boolean true
      'delete_private_posts' => boolean true
      'edit_private_posts' => boolean true
      'read_private_posts' => boolean true
      'delete_private_pages' => boolean true
      'edit_private_pages' => boolean true
      'read_private_pages' => boolean true
      'delete_users' => boolean true
      'create_users' => boolean true
      'unfiltered_upload' => boolean true
      'edit_dashboard' => boolean true
      'update_plugins' => boolean true
      'delete_plugins' => boolean true
      'install_plugins' => boolean true
      'update_themes' => boolean true
      'install_themes' => boolean true
      'update_core' => boolean true
      'list_users' => boolean true
      'remove_users' => boolean true
      'add_users' => boolean true
      'promote_users' => boolean true
      'edit_theme_options' => boolean true
      'delete_themes' => boolean true
      'export' => boolean true
      'administrator' => boolean true
  public 'filter' => null
```

Comment: Are you logged in?  I'd guess you know this, but you need to logged in for it to work.

Comment: @AndyWarren Yep. It gets all my info except first/last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoa! It is randomly working now.

1. Set first and last name under "My Account"
2. Log out
3. Log back in
4. Walk away for 30 mins
5. Do another var_dump()

Now, I'm a Computer Science major, and I've never seen computer magic until now.

But seriously, probably was retaining old cookies regarding my user info until I logged out and then back in.

Comment: Thank god for this find, otherwise I would have been driving myself crazy for ever trying to figure it out